# Which activation function should I use for my output layer if my output is a Glove vector representing a word

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, activation-function

My output is 332 dimension (300 glove + 32 my custom vector)
values of this vector range from -1 to +1
I got horrible results using sigmoid as it confined the output to 0 to 1.
I'm trying Tanh right now.
What about Softmax?
does it suit my case?

Comment: Can you elaborate? What is your end goal? What your model should do? Do you just want to calculate embeddings (for not known in GloVe words or calculate __additional__ 32 features - I didn't understand that part: `300 glove + 32 my custom vector`)? Your question is not clear...

Comment: Hey @MaxU , I'm working on a confidential project, so I can't share It here. My email Id is nsvikas1998@gmail.com . Could you please mail me? I saw from your profile you have very good experience in Machine Learning. I really need your help.!